# Marking comments and annotations on top of a PDF

Tags: linux, pdf, gui, pdf-editor, academia

I occasionally receive PDFs on which I want to mark comments, or some points/segments of which I want to annotate somehow - similarly to what I would do with printed PDFs.

This does not mean editing the contents - which stays just as it is - only addition of (clearly differentiable) comments - "red pen" style - on the page.

So - I want a piece of software which does this.

Required features:

- Works on Linux
- GUI of course
- Does not mess up the layout of the PDF (i.e. additions-only)
- Reasonable responsiveness on "heavy" and long PDF documents

Note I haven't listed a license requirements

Desired features:

- Gratis
- Libre license
- Can save the PDF-cum-comments as another PDF file, which will display properly, with the comments, in a typical PDF reader
- Actively maintained
- Offers extra functionality when noticing the PDF was created a certain way, e.g. with LaTeX, or LibreOffice, or Microsoft Office etc.
- Supports both comments and annotations
- Supports multiple comment authors (e.g. with different color comments)
- Doesn't make it easy to edit the PDF when I don't want to edit it.
- Allows extracting/saving the comments/annotations as plain text or some other format convertible to plain text.

Comment: *Doesn't make it easy to edit the PDF when I don't want to edit it.* – What do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean, that I can't, say, click someplace near to where I want to put my comment and find myself with an edit box for the PDF's text line, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far I have been using [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose and I am quite happy with it.
It essentially allows you to draw on top of the PDF using text and primitive drawing routines.

Regarding your criteria:

- *Linux* – yes
- *GUI* – yes
- *additions-only* – yes
- *responsiveness* – I haven’t had any challenging cases yet, but so far everything works fine.
- *gratis* – yes
- *Libre license* – yes, GPL
- *Can save the PDF-cum-comments as another PDF file* – yes, with some people using exotic software had problems with my PDFs, but those could be fixed by using a PDF printer instead of the native PDF exporting function.
- *Actively maintained* – yes, last update was two months ago
- *Offers extra functionality when noticing the PDF was created a certain way* – no
- *Supports both comments and annotations* – not really. You draw on the PDF, so the comments do not make use of a special PDF functionality intended for this purpose.
- *Supports multiple comment authors (e.g. with different color comments)* – Makeshift. You can comment with multiple colours, but there is no explicit collaborative functionality or similar that I am aware of.
- *Doesn't make it easy to edit the PDF when I don't want to edit it.* – Yes, editing the PDF’s text is impossible.
- *Allows extracting/saving the comments/annotations as plain text or some other format convertible to plain text.* – Not that I am aware of.

Comment: So, the GUI is not super-convenient, but it gets the job done. Thanks! ... keeping this open in the hope of something which doesn't make me curse my mouse clicking inaccuracy all the time...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at Elsevier's [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com) research paper sharing and management software, and its desktop client specifically. Note that it is a lot more than just a PDF annotation tool it is a research tool that covers a lot more areas.

It allows you to annotate PDF files with:

- General Notes i.e. notes on the whole file
- Sticky Notes i.e. notes with specific locations
- Text Highlights in multiple colours
- Area Highlights in multiple colours

All annotations are tagged with who added them & when.

Required features:

- Works on Linux *desktop client: **Yes** & Windows & Mac OS There is also a web interface and iOS/Android apps.*
- GUI of course ***Yes***
- Does not mess up the layout of the PDF (i.e. additions-only) ***Yes***
- Reasonable responsiveness on "heavy" and long PDF documents *I have not had any problems*

Desired features:

- Gratis ***Yes for the Free Account*** *with some limitations currently 2GB personal document storage, up to 5 private groups of up to 25 people with up to 2GB of storage across all groups. Additional storage via paid plans*
- Libre license ***No*** *this is a commercial tool aimed specifically at academia*
- Can save the PDF-cum-comments as another PDF file, which will display properly, with the comments, in a typical PDF reader ***Yes*** *"Export to PDF" does this giving you a choice of exporting the annotated document or just the annotations*
- Actively maintained ***Yes***
- Offers extra functionality when noticing the PDF was created a certain way, e.g. with LaTeX, or LibreOffice, or Microsoft Office etc.
- Supports both comments and annotations ***Yes***
- Supports multiple comment authors (e.g. with different color comments) ***Yes*** *You can select colours and all comments & highlights are marked with who & when.*
- Doesn't make it easy to edit the PDF when I don't want to edit it. ***Yes*** The comments and highlights are stored separately from the PDF the original file does not get changed at all.
- Allows extracting/saving the comments/annotations as plain text or some other format convertible to plain text. ***Yes*** *You can use the tool to export to several academic formats (BibTex, Research Information Systems & Endnote XML) - there is also a GPL python tool [Menotexport](https://github.com/Xunius/Menotexport) available for exporting to text files which is both command line & GUI based last update to Menotexport at the time of writing was 8 days ago.*

Comment: This is great, except for the license and its being by... I shudder to even write their name... Elsevier. +1 of course.

Comment: @einpoklum If I knew of a FOSS package that was anywhere near as good then I would recommend that but as it is ....

Comment: If it weren't Elsevier, then ok, but it's just that they're so evil :-(

Answer (score 2):

[Okular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okular) supported annotations for some time, but since recently, you can also save the annotated PDF using the native PDF annotation format. You can mark specific text passages and add a comment to this; you can also place comments not anchored to a specific text and draw freehand or straight lines, polygons, and ellipses. I recently used this for annotating proofs of a paper and reports I graded and it could do everything I wanted.

Regarding your criteria:

- *Linux* – yes
- *GUI* – yes
- *additions-only* – yes
- *responsiveness* – I only tested short documents so far.
- *gratis* – yes
- *Libre license* – yes, GPL
- *Can save the PDF-cum-comments as another PDF file* – yes, **since version 0.15, requiring Poppler 0.20** (according to several sources)
- *Actively maintained* – [yes](https://github.com/KDE/okular/releases)
- *Offers extra functionality when noticing the PDF was created a certain way* – no
- *Supports both comments and annotations* – yes
- *Supports multiple comment authors (e.g. with different color comments)* – Each comment shows its author. Different colours are not supported.
- *Doesn't make it easy to edit the PDF when I don't want to edit it.* – Yes, modifying the underlying PDF is impossible.
- *Allows extracting/saving the comments/annotations as plain text or some other format convertible to plain text.* – Yes, Okular stores annotations in an XML format in your config files (`.local/share/okular/docdata/` for me).

Comment: I should really give this another try, after being basically (though not perfectly) satisfied with Xournal so far.

Comment: ... after giving it another try, this doesn't cut it. It's very difficult to place text onto the PDF (which is the basic functionality I'm after): You can only put it in a colored box; you can move it after insertion; it defaults to an annoying background yellow; you cant make the background transparent without making the text transparent as well... In short - anything is better than this.